# What video editor should I use for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04. I'm trying to make a video with text graphics and a few video clips from my phone. Since Adobe AfterEffects is out of the question, does anybody know a decent Video Editor that runs on Ubuntu?

Something like Gimp perhaps, only for videos.

Comment: Thanks Matan and Journeyman for the answers. +1 for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CinePaint](http://www.cinepaint.org/)
Free and powerful editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think [pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org/) looks promising if you're a newbie to it - nice simple interface , and its in the repositories. There was some noise about it going to be the default at some point